# como puedo unir mi codigo para que asi tenga un arreglo de objetos aleatorios desde api

Tags: javascript, html

/** Crear un script que consuma La Api https://api.got.show/api/

- Listar 10  personajes aleatorios con los campos Titulo, Nombre y casa.
- los datos deben ser mostrados de esta manera " Ser Addam Marbrand, House Marbrand"
- Mostrar datos consumidos en la consola
- puede usar fetch o axios*/

hasta ahora tengo esto y no se como seleccionar solo 10 personajes aleatorios, ya que si ejecuto me salen todos los personajes en un lista

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.got.show/api/show/characters'
    }).then(res => {
        const list = document.getElementById('list')
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
        for (const userInfo of res.data) {
            const listItem = document.createElement('LI')
            listItem.textContent = `Ser ${userInfo.name} de la casa ${userInfo.house} y soy el ${userInfo.titles} `
            fragment.appendChild(listItem)
        }
        list.appendChild(fragment)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>axios</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Axios - Get</h1>
  <button id="button">Get Data</button>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://api.got.show/api/show/characters"></script>
  <script src="Api.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: casi lo tienes, con un `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`  solo lo haria 10 veces https://jsfiddle.net/87ar6ejv/1/ despues solo faltaria cambiar res.data[i] por [`res.data[Math.Random()]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Amigo y para añadir una imagen como sería?

Comment: Has mirado en [Google](https://www.letmegooglethat.com/?q=a%C3%B1adir+imagen+javascript)?

Comment: Amino no sé cómo integrarlo el for y el math